# String.split by semicolon

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split a string by semicolon(";"):

```
String phrase = "‫;‪14/May/2015‬‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid";
String[] dateSplit = phrase.split(";");
System.out.println("dateSplit[0]:" + dateSplit[0]);
System.out.println("dateSplit[1]:" + dateSplit[1]);
```

But it removes the ";" from string and puts all string to 'datesplit[1](http://ideone.com/vBo5bs)' 
so the output is:

```
dateSplit[0]:‫
dateSplit[1]:‪14/May/2015‬‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid`
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/vBo5bs)

and on doing

```
System.out.println("Real String :"+phrase);
```

string printed is

```
Real String :‫;‪14/May/2015‬‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid
```

Comment: Your "phrase" variable is not correctly formatted. Show us the actual code and we might be able to help.

Comment: when you split with any character then that character will be not part of your array. Here if you want ';' then you have to add manually after dateSplit[0]+";"

Comment: I smell possible encoding issue here.

Comment: @vdwijngaert actually the phrase is really what it is.

Comment: Your code is working fine on my system.

Comment: @Pratik and I think I should  have "14/May/2015" in dateSplit[0] and "‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid" in dateSplit[1]

Comment: @s_puria if you want 14/May/2015 as your first index then it is working fine...

Comment: @s_puria No way, this won't even compile.

Comment: try adding `phrase = new String(phrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` right after first line of code and see the result

Comment: @s_puria as it appears right now, the String is just made of Madrid and what follows make the code non - compilable

Comment: When I copied your code on my system, it got copied like this `‪String phrase = ";14/May/2015‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid";`

Comment: There is an invisible character on position 0 and 2 in your phrase String, which is not UTF-8, hence the issue. Depending on the browser/os it may get clipboarded or not...

Comment: @MarounMaroun I agree with you the string declaration should give an compilation error but its compiling fine I have checked it.I dont get the reason yet

Comment: while copying it to mine system it is changing as @NamanGala told!

Comment: Some of us see this differently than others. To me it looks perfectly compilable, but I agree with @Palcente - there is an invisible character in the beginning of the string.

Comment: in UTF-8 this string looks like this:
`"?;?14/May/2015?? ??FC?? ??Barcelona?? ??VS.?? ??Real?? ??Madrid"`

Comment: for me output is like `dateSplit[0]:?
dateSplit[1]:?14/May/2015?? ??FC?? ??Barcelona?? ??VS.?? ??Real?? ??Madrid` in UTF-8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `phrase` contains [bi-directional characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) like [right-to-left embedding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202b/index.htm). It's why some editors don't manage to display correctly the string.

This piece of code shows the actual characters in the `String` (for some people the `phrase` won't display here the right way, but it compiles and looks fine in Eclipse). I just translate **left-right** with **->**, **right-to-left** with **<-** and **pop directions** with **^**:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String phrase = "‫;‪14/May/2015‬‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid";
    String[] dateSplit = phrase.split(";");
    for (String d : dateSplit) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
    char[] c = phrase.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length;i++) {
        int code = Character.codePointAt(c, i);
        switch (code) {
        case 8234:
            p.append(" -> ");
            break;
        case 8235:
            p.append(" <- ");
            break;
        case 8236:
            p.append(" ^ ");
            break;
        default:
            p.append(c[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

Prints:

> <- ; -> 14/May/2015 ^  ^   <-  -> FC ^  ^   <-  -> Barcelona ^  ^   <-  -> VS. ^  ^   <-  -> Real ^  ^   <-  -> Madrid

The `String#split()` will work on the *actual* character string and not on what the editor displays, hence you can see the `;` is the second character after a *right-to-left*, which gives (beware of display again: the `;` is not part of the string in `dateSplit[1]`):

> dateSplit[0] = "";
>   dateSplit[1] = "14/May/2015‬‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid";

I guess you are processing data from a language writing/reading from right-to-left and there is some mixing with the football team names which are left-to-right. The solution is certainly to get rid of directional characters and put the `;` at the right place, i.e as a separator for the token.

Answer (score 1):

I `rewrote` your code, instead of coping from here and its working perfectly fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phrase = "14/May/2015; FC Barcelona VS. Real Madrid";
    String[] dateSplit = phrase.split(";");
    System.out.println("dateSplit[0]:" + dateSplit[0]);
    System.out.println("dateSplit[1]:" + dateSplit[1]);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/FCQoem)

Comment: this is not the string OP posted

Comment: there are some hidden character in string which OP posted

Comment: @Palcente, Oh I see, i thought OP is trying with this text which is visible in the question.

Comment: @s_puria, is this you wanted? Or there is some hidden character?

Comment: There are some hidden charracters.

Comment: There were some kind of hidden characters in my code and I think it was RTL. but it showed LTR.

Answer (score 0):

Cut and pasting your code into IntelliJ screwed up the editor; as @Palcente said, possible encoding issues.

However, I would recommend usinge a StringTokenizer instead.

```
StringTokenizer sTok = new StringTokenizer(phrase, ";");
```

You can then iterate over it, which leads to nicer (and safer) code.

Comment: You say: *"However, I would recommend usinge a StringTokenizer instead. You can then iterate over it, which leads to nicer (and safer) code."*, [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says: *"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."*. What should someone new to Java think? :P

Comment: @Tom hmm, hadn't noticed that, probably because it hasn't been annotated as Deprecated (also, I can't remember the last time I actually used a StringTokenizer).  Good to know.